# How to get the height of a minipage right?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, height, box

I am trying to get the height of a minipage by using a box. I have found several threads where they solve it this way. However, if I use the height to draw a vertical line (the vertical line is just as an example) with tikz it is not equal to the height of the text/minipage. I cannot find the problem. Can anyone of you help me out? Cheers!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\testheight}
\newsavebox{\mpb}


\newcommand{\makeformalities}{%
    \sbox{\mpb}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
        \lipsum[1]\\
        
        \lipsum[1]\\
        
        \lipsum[1]\\
        
    \end{minipage}
    }
    %
    \settoheight{\testheight}{\usebox{\mpb}}
    \usebox{\mpb}
    %   
    \begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [blue] (0,0) -- (0,-\testheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{minipage}

    height is \the\testheight
}


\begin{document}
    \makeformalities
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you hav used `\begin{minipage}[t]` so the height is the height above the baseline of the firs line of text. This box has a large _depth_ not height.  Note also you are adding a space at the start and end of your `\sbox` so `\usebox`  will produce a box that is two spaces wider than the original minipage.

Comment: Thanks, that was the trick! :) I will post the result as answer. Correct me if I still miss something.

Comment: You can also use `{\dimexpr \ht\mpb+\dp\mpb}`

Answer (score 3):

David Carlisle help me out. The relevant feature is the box depth. Here is a working example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\testheight}
\newsavebox{\mpb}


\newcommand{\makeformalities}{%
    \sbox{\mpb}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \lipsum[1]\\
        
        \lipsum[1]\\
        
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}%
    }
    %
    \settodepth{\testheight}{\usebox{\mpb}}
    \usebox{\mpb}
    %   
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [blue] (0,0) -- (0,-\testheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{minipage}

    height is \the\testheight
}


\begin{document}
    \makeformalities
\end{document}
```

[image]